# SceneKit: getting points on node edges

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I've got a 3D object, as in the attached picture.
I need to collect critical (saddle) points located on its edges - in particular on one side of it (marked with lighter green on the picture).
These should approximate the best the curve that this object's edge in fact is.

Can you guide me please on how it could be achieved?
I'm guessing the task needs to be split into two:

- finding the edge and representing it as a curve
- identifying a set of critical points on that curve.

[image: Example node]

Comment: I dont really understand what you are trying to achive. Have you tryed the Bounding Box?

Comment: See the lighter green color on the picture? I'd like to collect points located on that "stripe", that are critical for it, being kind of approximation of that curve (the more points the closer you get to that curve). Does it make sense @ZAY

Comment: well, I guess, what you try to achive is really tricky. In my opinion you have to know the exact vertex positions of the regions of that stripe.
You could probybly do some hittesting against the surface, which will give you some position values.

Comment: yep, that was my idea
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult

there are 2 problems though:
- how "dense" should be that hit testing
- after collecting points lying on that curve, how to select, let's say, 50 that are the most characteristic?

Comment: you could try to make a kind of grid of x,y positions with a fixed z-position and fire as many hittests you want to. against the geometry. some of the hittests will be more close to the point of where you release the hittest (look for the z-positions). those which are above some treshold value could represent the shape you are looking for...